# Invalid date formatting

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel 5.8 I need to make filter for current month and I do :

```
    $start_date = new DateTime('first day of this month');
    $start_time = clone $start_date->setTime(0, 0, 0);
    $end_date = new DateTime('last day of this month');
    $end_time = $end_date->setTime(23, 59, 59);
```

...

```
   ->whereRaw( "created_at >= '" . date ('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start_time->date) . "' and created_at <= '" . date ('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end_time->date) . "' ")
```

But tracing I see invalid date formatted, as :

```
AND created_at >= '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Which is valid way to format datetime?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Have you checked what `$start_time->date` contains, and which input format is expected by `date`? Why not use `$start_time->date->format()` to format a `DateTime`?

Comment: What is `$start_time->date` even supposed to be? `DateTime` has no such property, which PHP should be giving you a notice for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try this:

```php
$startDate = new DateTime('first day of this month');
$endDate = new DateTime('last day of this month');
        
ExampleModel::query()
     ->whereBetween(\DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'), [$startDate->format('Y-m-d'), $endDate->format('Y-m-d')]);
```